# Implementing code first model in mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use code first model for my simple blog site, I'm used to with database first, but an experienced guy told me to use code first, but I'm having lots of trouble to implement this, even the simplest thing like setting identity to the key value, defining relation between two entity, handling image type data. I do want to understand the inside out of this approach, I tried to search quite a lot, but didn't get the desired information. Can someone please help me with the information like where to start, how to proceed & get expertize on the code first model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have any problem in studying, so any reference will also do.

Comment: did you even *try* a google search? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj590134

Comment: Yes, off course I did, but I was not satisfied from what I got there. They are showing just a few things to demonstrate their example, but I need to know details. I believe any dedicated book will help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you ask the experienced guy that told you to use code-first for help? Once you have some specific question with your code you could come back here, show your progress and explain what difficulties you have encountered. You will most certainly get help. But asking how should I learn a specific technology is not a question that is a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this: [Entity Framework Code First to Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj193542) on MSDN.

Even better, the tutorial uses a Blog as the example application.

Comment: I already read an article on msdn, but didn't get all the required info, any way let me check this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of tutorial out there on code-first approach.

you can start with asp.net mvc official site: http://www.asp.net/mvc

here is another tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1 (Code First Approach)

and you can find a lot projects here: http://www.codeplex.com/ you just need to search

Comment: Thanks mate...I will check these out. May be I was not searching with proper key word, Thanks for your time.